# Can someone help me create a simple vertical bar chart using google charts?

Tags: charts, bar-chart

I need help in building a dynamic chart. i have the following code but need to change it to a vertical bar graph instead of the horizontal one here is the sample http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhs&chs=200x50&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd&chxt=x,y&chxs=0|0&chd=t:80|20

Answer (score 5):

You can change the "bhs" to "bvs" and change the scaling as needed:
[Try this.](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=200x50&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd&chxt=x,y&chxs=0|0&chd=t:80|20)