# Google Chart Tools - How to create stacked bar chart

Tags: charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone help me create a simple vertical bar chart using google charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146148/can-someone-help-me-create-a-simple-vertical-bar-chart-using-google-charts)

Im using new Google Chart Tools, and I want to create stacked bar chart format.

Answer (score 28):

The Google Developers site gives some details on the bar chart format: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

To make a normal bar chart stacked, you need to user the `isStacked: true` option. You can copy and paste the following code into the Chart Tools playground to see a working example:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Denmark', 'Greece'],
    ['2003',  1336060,    400361,    1001582,   997974],
    ['2004',  1538156,    366849,    1119450,   941795],
    ['2005',  1576579,    440514,    993360,    930593],
    ['2006',  1600652,    434552,    1004163,   897127],
    ['2007',  1968113,    393032,    979198,    1080887],
    ['2008',  1901067,    517206,    916965,    1056036]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups"},
            isStacked: true}
      );
}
```

You might also be interested in a Stacked Area Chart, depending on what data you are trying to display.

There is also a question which gives an example of a stacked bar chart using the Chart Tools Image API: [Bar chart in Javascript: stacked bars + grouped bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043236/bar-chart-in-javascript-stacked-bars-grouped-bars)

Note that the Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools was officially deprecated on the 20th April, 2012. Image charts will still work for a while as per Google's deprecation policy, but I recommend you concentrate on the interactive HTML5+SVG implementation described above.