# create single bar with different data using Google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Can I create these types of charts using Google charts where I can set the target at top also.

Are these charts bar type. I didn't find anything which can make bar charts like this or is this a completely different chart type.

**Edit**

I found the solution at [Google Chart Tools - How to create stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441838/google-chart-tools-how-to-create-stacked-bar-chart). These are stacked bar charts. but still I didn't find how to put target at the top

Comment: I found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441838/google-chart-tools-how-to-create-stacked-bar-chart. These are stacked bar charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ComboChart, and set the `series.<series index>.type` option to `'bars'` for the "Pending", "Loss", and "Won" series.  Set the `series.<series index>.type` to `'steppedArea'` and `series.<series index>.opacity` to `0` for the "Target" series.  Set the `connectSteps` option to `false`.  Here's one way to do it, assuming your data is in the order "Won", "Loss", "Pending", "Target":

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    isStacked: true,
    connectSteps: false,
    series: {
        0: {
            // Won
            type: 'bars'
        },
        1: {
            // Loss
            type: 'bars'
        },
        2: {
            // Pending
            type: 'bars'
        },
        3: {
            // Target
            type: 'steppedArea',
            areaOpacity: 0
        }
    }
});
```